# Trouble with OpenNMT Toy Example (Python3.9)

Tags: python-3.x, opennmt

I recently installed OpenNMT but getting the following error when going through the toy example.

I have macOS Big Sur 11.2.1
I have python2.7 and python3.9 installed.

`pip install --upgrade OpenNMT-py==2.0.0rc1`

`wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/opennmt-trainingdata/toy-ende.tar.gz`

`tar xf toy-ende.tar.gz`

`cd toy_ende`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/onmt_build_vocab", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onmt/bin/build_vocab.py", line 63, in main
    build_vocab_main(opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onmt/bin/build_vocab.py", line 23, in build_vocab_main
    ArgumentParser.validate_prepare_opts(opts, build_vocab_only=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onmt/utils/parse.py", line 127, in validate_prepare_opts
    cls._validate_data(opt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onmt/utils/parse.py", line 42, in _validate_data
    cls._validate_file(path_src, info=f'{cname}/path_src')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/onmt/utils/parse.py", line 18, in _validate_file
    raise IOError(f"Please check path of your {info} file!")
OSError: Please check path of your corpus_1/path_src file!
```

Comment: The directory is `toy-ende`, not `toy_ende`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this procedure:

```sh
pip install --upgrade OpenNMT-py==2.0.0rc1;
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/opennmt-trainingdata/toy-ende.tar.gz;
tar xf toy-ende.tar.gz;
echo '## Where the samples will be written
save_data: toy-ende/run/example
## Where the vocab(s) will be written
src_vocab: toy-ende/run/example.vocab.src
tgt_vocab: toy-ende/run/example.vocab.tgt
# Prevent overwriting existing files in the folder
overwrite: False

# Corpus opts:
data:
    corpus_1:
        path_src: toy-ende/src-train.txt
        path_tgt: toy-ende/tgt-train.txt
    valid:
        path_src: toy-ende/src-val.txt
        path_tgt: toy-ende/tgt-val.txt
' > toy_en_de.yaml;
mkdir toy-ende/run;
touch toy-ende/run/example.vocab.src;
touch toy-ende/run/example.vocab.tgt;
onmt_build_vocab -config toy_en_de.yaml -n_sample 10000;

echo '# Vocabulary files that were just created
src_vocab: toy-ende/run/example.vocab.src
tgt_vocab: toy-ende/run/example.vocab.tgt

# Train on a single GPU
world_size: 1
gpu_ranks: [0]

# Where to save the checkpoints
save_model: toy-ende/run/model
save_checkpoint_steps: 500
train_steps: 1000
valid_steps: 500
' >> toy_en_de.yaml;
onmt_train -config toy_en_de.yaml;
```

If you do not have a GPU, you need to remove or comment the following lines:

```py
# Train on a single GPU
world_size: 1
gpu_ranks: [0]
```

Comment: So should I be running the omnt_build and onmt_train command outside of the toy-ende folder?

Comment: What happens if I get a `AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'` error after trying to run the training command? Thanks

Comment: @JoseChavez Run those commands from the folder that is parent to `toy-ende` folder and it should work. Since it seems you have no GPU on board, you can only run on CPU, and to do that, you need to comment out `world_size: 1` and `gpu_ranks: [0]` lines in the `*.yml` file, see [here](https://forum.opennmt.net/t/train-model-with-cpu-only-using-python/4157).

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know how I can run this on a google colab GPU? Thanks

Comment: @JoseChavez Please check [this "Quick Start Python Only Colab" OpenNMT forum page](https://forum.opennmt.net/t/quick-start-python-only-colab/4381).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the quick response.